# ionic fails to load html and css of a component in an npm package

Tags: html, css, npm, ionic2, package

I am trying to create a npm package that will have a angular2 dummy component i.e. a .ts file which references its .css file and .html file.

When I install this package in an angular project, it works fine referencing the relative paths of html and css files.

However the same fails to load html and css files in an IONIC2 project.

I believed ionic2 is made using angular2 and this should have worked.

My tsconfig.json looks like -

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "dom"
        ],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "outDir": "../dist",
        "declarationDir": "../dist",
        "declaration": true
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist"
    ] }
```

and package.json -

```
{
  "name": "componentlibrarytest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "test components"
  ],
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6",
    "typescript": "~2.3.2"
  },
  "author": "XYZ",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I guess I am missing something to bundle up html and css files. Do i need to use webpack or something?